# Pandas merge of two dataframes works on one column but not all

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

```
df1:
    Name       Age       Gender      Phone
    John       50           M          123458
    James      60           M          1234522
    Jenny     40           F         123459
    Zoe       51           F         1234566

df2:

        Name       Age       City       Country
        John       50          Sydney     AUS         
        James      60         London     UK
        Jenny     40          NY           USA
        Zoe       51          Melbourne    AUS
```

I run the following merge:

```
    df1= df1.merge(df2, left_on=['Name', 'Age'],right_on=['Name','Age'], how='outer'
, suffixes=('', '_DROP')).filter(regex='^(?!.*_DROP)')
```

Then I get an output that looks like:

```
    df1:
        Name       Age       Gender      Phone          City     Country
        John       50           M          123458                   AUS
        James      60           M          1234522                  UK
        Jenny     40           F         123459                    USA
        Zoe       51           F         1234566                    AUS
        John                                           Sydney               
        James                                          London      
        Jenny                                          NY            
        Zoe                                            Melbourne
```

I'm not sure why one column matches (therefore the join columns match) however one column doesn't? Really bizzare and not sure how to troubleshoot!

Thanks very much!

Comment: hmm just tried that for both and it still comes up with the same

Comment: cant reproduce, the merge command works fine for me with your sample dataframes

Comment: Thanks! Yeah my dataset is a bit hard to replicate. But I’m more wondering what issue It could be and any troubleshooting tips to try

Comment: Ahh my bad actually. The column names match however the `Name` column looks like its values has whitespaces. Try this `df1['Name'] = df1['Name'].str.strip()` same for df2, then merge

Comment: Still the same issue. Any other potential errors that you could think of?

Comment: No unfortunately :(

Comment: How about `df2['Name'] = df2['Name'].str.strip()`? Do this for the unmatched column.

Comment: Probably both dfs contain spaces in `Name` column? Then you need both `df1['Name'] = df1['Name'].str.strip()` and `df2['Name'] = df2['Name'].str.strip()` and then run your merging. Else, you need to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks guys! realised it was a datatyoe issue, `Age` was a string in df1 and am integer in df 2. Thanks everyone for your help!!